# How to change the default web server ip(127.0.0.1) of Flutter Web app

Tags: flutter, ip, flutter-web

Change the default IP(127.0.0.1) of flutter web App.

I have created a flutter web application, when I run the web app the ip which assigned is 127.0.0.1 but i am unable to access the same app with my local IP over LAN. So please help on how can i change this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**update**

`webdev` is no longer used for launching `flutter web` applications. Now use:

```
 flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 8989
```

**original answer**

Start the app with command:

> webdev server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0

Or replace 0.0.0.0 with your actual ip address.

Answer (score 9):

You can add this command line parameter 
`--web-hostname 0.0.0.0`.

( `--hostname` doesn't work now. )

So when you start your web server you would start like this :

> `flutter run -d chrome --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 55555`

This will allow you to access your web app from any device in your LAN network by accessing the url :

`http://your-local-ip:55555`

Comment: You save my day :)

Comment: this command is not working. It says "Target file "web-server" not found". If we remove **chrome** between -d and  --web-hostname, it is working.