# Docker - Flutter Web deployment - Site cannot be reached

Tags: docker, flutter, docker-compose, flutter-web

I'm using Docker and Flutter Web. I just finished setting up Docker and Compose for it. 
My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG PROJECT_DIR=/srv/api
ENV PATH=/opt/flutter/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        xz-utils \
        git \
        openssh-client \
        curl && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt

RUN curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable.tar.xz | tar -C /opt -xJ

RUN apt-get install -y lib32stdc++6

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_DIR}
COPY ./ ./

RUN flutter doctor
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter packages pub global activate webdev
RUN flutter packages upgrade
```

My `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  api:
    container_name: flutter-web-test
    restart: always
    image: flutter-web-test
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: ["flutter", "pub", "global", "run", "webdev", "serve", "web:5001"]
```

After executing `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml build` and `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`, I receive that server should be up.

```
flutter-web-test | web

flutter-web-test | [WARNING] Throwing away cached asset graph due to Dart SDK update.


flutter-web-test | [INFO] Cleaning up outputs from previous builds. completed, took 76ms

flutter-web-test | [INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 2.5s

flutter-web-test | [INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 2ms

flutter-web-test | [INFO] Serving `web` on http://127.0.0.1:5001
```

However, when I try to connect to http://127.0.0.1:5001 - I see `This site cannot be reached` window.

If I run it locally, it works perfectly fine. I believe I must have skipped something in Docker, but cannot find an issue. Anyone can help to spot an issue?

Comment: The web server should be listening for connections on 0.0.0.0, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56967978) and the port needs to be published (is “ports” indeed)

Comment: Note: the docker daemon volume mapping is incorrect (“/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock”).

Comment: Thank you, @masseyb, you saved my day again. It's working now. However, another issue appeared. Investigating it now

Comment: Sure - added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57752520/1423507) with link for details regarding `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `webdev` server should be listening on [`0.0.0.0`](https://superuser.com/a/949522/382718) like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56967978/1423507).

The service [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) should be mapped to the host and the `docker` daemon path should be `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  api:
    container_name: flutter-web-test
    restart: always
    image: flutter-web-test
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: ["flutter", "pub", "global", "run", "webdev", "serve", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0:5001"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/) in your docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  api:
    container_name: flutter-web-test
    restart: always
    image: flutter-web-test
    port:
      - "5001":"5001"
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: ["flutter", "pub", "global", "run", "webdev", "serve", "web:5001"]
```

Comment: Little syntax error there as is should be 
```ports:
      - 5001:5001
```

However, after running it, same issue. Doesn't work. Error message changed though. Now it's ```This page isn't working```