# I cannot access my localhost from my iphone

Tags: flutter, localhost

Basically I wanna access the server running on my MacBooks localhost from my iPhone in order to fully test my flutter application. I am on the same network but I cannot access it through my MacBooks IP address. I tried shutting down the firewall but that didn't work either. I then tried to connect my iPhone through USB and enable it via "internet sharing" from my Mac but it still did not work...

Comment: It could be that you need to bind to 0.0.0.0 to access it from another device on the same network. See [How to change the default web server ip(127.0.0.1) of Flutter Web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967885/how-to-change-the-default-web-server-ip127-0-0-1-of-flutter-web-app)

Comment: (can we tweet the subject to reflect the problem with the local network?)

Answer (score 1):

**Localhost** It's not an external IP. 
**Localhost** Cannot be accessed from other machines.
**localhost** refers to the internal address of the machine that is running the server.

if you want to know the IP address of your MacBook, you must look up your IP in your network.

Open a **terminal** and write `ifconfig` to know what is your local IP address.

You might have several **IPs** there, just **make sure your phone is connected to the same Network as your Mac**, or just use your MacBook as a **Hotspot**, and check what's the IP of the machine.

Make sure that the server you are running is not being blocked by any Firewall

Comment: yea I know what "localhost" is... As I mentioned I am on the same network and I got my MacBooks ip address from the network settings. I shut off my firewall but it I still can't access it...

Comment: You must be on the same local network for this to work. Create a Wifi AP from your Mac and connect your phone to it. Use an app to discover Wi-Fi LAN devices from the phone to check if it can reach the MacBook's local IP.
If you don't want to create an AP, use the IP given by your home router.

Comment: Whether you are on Wifi or Ethernet, it's common enough these days where the devices cannot see each other even if they are on the same IP range. (This could be deliberate or unintentional). Also remember that PING with ICMP is not proof that your connection will work, use a browser request to verify.

Comment: @benc **Ping literally proves you have a connection between 2 machines**, they can see each other, and communicate. If your application doesn't reach the server or doesn't get a response, that's another thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a macOS device to run your local server, try the following:

1. Get your IP address by holding down <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> and clicking on the Wi-Fi icon in your status bar. If you're connected through ethernet go to `System Settings → Network → (Your Ethernet Device)` to view your IP address.
2. **If you have a firewall enabled**, disable it. ***Then restart your machine*** to ensure the changes have taken affect. (This was what got me).
3. Make sure both the iOS and macOS device are on the same network, start your local server, and then try connecting.
4. Then if you want, you can re-enable your firewall. Then click <kbd>Options...</kbd> and **ensure** that the applications (Terminal, Visual Studio Code, and so on) you're using to run your local server **can accept incoming connections**. Restart to verify your changes have taken affect.